# Fix for "Wireless disabled by hardware key" in dual boot system win8.1/Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: wireless, dual-boot, intel, centrino

I have a dual boot system with windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.04 I upgraded from windows 7 and since then I have been unable to browse via wireless on Ubuntu I have tried all the tips I can find but none seem to work.
Kindly assist.
machine is a HP Pavilion dm4-2070us 
wireless is Intel Centrino-1000

Answer (score 1):

On your specific machine the action key <kbd>F12</kbd> turns the wireless feature on or off.

Action keys are customized actions that are assigned to specific keys at the top of the keyboard. To use an action key, press and hold this key to activate the assigned function.

The action key feature is enabled at the factory. You can disable this feature in the BIOS and revert back to standard settings by pressing the fn key and one of the function keys to
activate the assigned function.<sup>HP</sup>

Comment: The Action Key is not working

Answer (score 0):

Well, the message is saying that some hardware key is causing the wireless to be disabled. There is no way Ubuntu can override this. The solution is to search for a wireless disable/enable key (often Fn+F5) and press it.

Comment: The laptop has a wireless key and pressing it does nothing would the upgrade on windows 7 changed it?